# How to enable Vue runtimeCompiler in a Nuxt 2 project?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to use `Vue` `runtimeCompiler` in a `Nuxt 2` project.
It's working fine in development mode, but not in production mode, because `runtimeCompiler` is not enabled by default in production mode.

In production it's returning this error: `TypeError: n.default.compile is not a function`

This is my component code:

```
import Vue from 'vue'

// ...

  watch: {
    template: {
      immediate: true,
      handler () {
        const res = Vue.compile(this.template) // this line does not work in production
        this.templateRender = res.render
        this.$options.staticRenderFns = []
        this._staticTrees = []

        for (const i in res.staticRenderFns) {
          this.$options.staticRenderFns.push(res.staticRenderFns[i])
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

The template i'm trying to compile is returned from a back-end api.

I've tried extending the build configuration with

```
extend (config) {
  config.resolve.alias.vue = 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js' // also tried vue/dist/common.js
}
```

but it still not work.

I've looked at Nuxt and Vue documentation in https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/nuxt-config/#runtimeconfig and https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#runtimecompiler but I didn't figured it out how to enable this option in Nuxt.